# systemVerilog - define a function which return vector/array with unknown size?

Tags: arrays, function, system-verilog

Can I define a function which return vector/array with unknown size?

Return values can be:

bit [15:0] , bit [10:0], bit [2:0]....

I want be able to define something like:

```
   function bit [] foo (int size, int mem, string mem_name);
   endfunction: foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic array/queue if you define a type for that. Other than that you can use **ref** and pass the array as a parameter.